# Calculate distance travelled on objects in Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently struggling to write a dynamic script that gets the position of two objects(hands) When I don't include public variables and put the script under each of the hands it works but not when I drag them in as game objects.There is no errors. The values just don't get updated.

This is an Oculus Rift application running on Unity 5.5 with the latest SDKs with Newton plug in.

```
public class calorieCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text displayMessage;

    public GameObject leftHand;
    public GameObject righHand;

    float distanceTravelledL = 0;
    float distanceTravelledR = 0;

    float distanceTravelled = 0;
    Vector3 lastPosition;

    Vector3 lastPositionL;
    Vector3 lastPositionR;

    void Start()
    {

        lastPositionL = leftHand.transform.position;
        lastPositionR = righHand.transform.position;
        lastPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {

        distanceTravelledL += Vector3.Distance(transform.position, lastPositionL);
        distanceTravelledR += Vector3.Distance(transform.position, lastPositionR);

        lastPositionL = transform.position;
        lastPositionR = transform.position;

        print("Left hand distance: " + distanceTravelledL);
        displayMessage.text = ("L: " + distanceTravelledL);


        print("Right hand Distace: " + distanceTravelledR);
        print("Right hand position: " + lastPositionR);
        print("Left hand position: " + lastPositionL);
        displayMessage.text += ("R: " + distanceTravelledR);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the objects you're dragging onto the public variables are actually the objects that are moving? (ie. They're not a static container object around the hand object that is actually moving?)

Comment: Yes they are moving. As I said it works until I set global variables and drag the objects in. I tried searching for the objects but it didn't help

Comment: Alright, I've identified the likely error in your code - let me know if my assessment with accurate, or if you're still facing issues with your implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed up some of your variables - in your `Update()` method, you're storing the last position as `transform.position`, instead of the respective positions of the hands. In the same way, your distance calculation should be based on the hands' positions, not the script's `transform.position`.

Here's some updated code that references the correct transforms:

```
void Update()
{
    distanceTravelledL += Vector3.Distance(leftHand.transform.position, lastPositionL);
    distanceTravelledR += Vector3.Distance(righHand.transform.position, lastPositionR);

    lastPositionL = leftHand.transform.position;
    lastPositionR = righHand.transform.position;

    // ...
}
```

On a side note, you should probably also remove `lastPosition` from the script if you're not using it - it looks like a relic from when you attached the script individually to both hands, and it could cause a similar mix-up if you're not careful.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much @Serlite ! It works. Can't believe I haven't noticed it.

Comment: @Pavol Glad to help out - sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes to spot a problem. Be sure to accept an answer that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark next to it. That way, it tells other people on the site that your question has been successfully solved.

Answer (score 0):

I guess just by doing this manually it can be like this

```
 Vector3 temp = new Vector3(0,0,0);
 myGameObject.transform.position += temp;
```

I hope it helps